# Navigation Bar will not become transparent

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar

I need the navigation bar to become transparent. Here is what i have put in my `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var navbar: UINavigationBar!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navbar.isTranslucent=true
    navbar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navbar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
  }
```

According to debug view hierarchy `UIVisualEffectBackdropView`, `UIVisualEffectSubview` and `UIVisualEffectSubview`(yes two of them) are preventing it from becoming transparent. 
Ps: I am not using a Navigation Controller.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This three lines should be enough to make your `UINavigationBar` transparent.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // make transparent the navbar
    navbar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navbar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navbar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

Comment: I just came back to delete the answer as i figured it out- exactly the same way as per your suggestion. I will accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Works for me. I' m using a Navigation Controller, so just instead your "navbar" used "navigationController?.navigationBar"

Answer (score 6):

If you build with the lastest beta iOS 13.4 and XCode 11.4, the xmhafiz answer won't work anymore.
I've found another way, maybe it's just a bug in the beta software, but I'm writing it down there, just in case

```
import UIKit

class TransparentNavBar :UINavigationBar {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.isTranslucent = true
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.standardAppearance.backgroundColor = .clear
            self.standardAppearance.backgroundEffect = .none
            self.standardAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        }
    }
}
```